# Will Facebook migration affect my application?

Tags: https, oauth, facebook-page

I have a Facebook application installed on a Facebook fan page which is a tab that displays a flash banner.

That is all. I am installing SSL on my domain. Do I need to change anything else? Should I update to OAuth 2.0 or that is not necessary for such a tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no other changes based on SSL: as long as you configure your application's secure URL correctly, everything else should be the same.

Comment: so i should not update to OAuth 2.0, honeslty im a newbie and don't know how to do that...